# Character Limit or Rules for Naming Android APK

Tags: android, apk

Is anyone aware of limits pertaining to naming an Android APK?  Not the package.  I have a client that was having problems with an apk not loading, but if the renamed the apk it loaded.  Is there a character limit or something else that would cause this?

Comment: may be same name in the folder shows already exist?.